Zebra Label Printer Not Updating from Commands
I've got ~20 Zebra label printers on a network that I update via a script written in python and primarily Set-Get-Do.
All but 3 update with commands from the script and I can't figure these out.
Choosing one for example, it responds to the following command:
{}{ "device.friendly_name":null, "device.location":null} with {'device.friendly_name': 'ZP1WC945_4x6','device.location': 'Shipping Prep'} as expected.
However, when I send the update command {}{ "device.friendly_name":'my_new_name', "device.location":'my_new_location'} it will not take these changes.
I want to know what I need to change for this printer to accept changes via commands I send to it with a script.
The model of the example printer is ZTC ZD621-203dpi ZPL (different from the other models in use and responding to commands) and the printer configuration is below.
View Printer Configuration
+10.0               DARKNESS
LOW                 DARKNESS SWITCH
6.0 IPS             PRINT SPEED
+000                TEAR OFF ADJUST
CUTTER              PRINT MODE
CONTINUOUS          MEDIA TYPE
TRANSMISSIVE        SENSOR SELECT
830                 PRINT WIDTH
1228                LABEL LENGTH
15.0IN   380MM      MAXIMUM LENGTH
MAINT. OFF          EARLY WARNING
NOT CONNECTED       USB COMM.
AUTO                SER COMM. MODE
9600                BAUD
8 BITS              DATA BITS
NONE                PARITY
XON/XOFF            HOST HANDSHAKE
NONE                PROTOCOL
NORMAL MODE         COMMUNICATIONS
<~>  7EH            CONTROL PREFIX
<^>  5EH            FORMAT PREFIX
<,>  2CH            DELIMITER CHAR
ZPL II              ZPL MODE
INACTIVE            COMMAND OVERRIDE
NO MOTION           MEDIA POWER UP
FEED                HEAD CLOSE
DEFAULT             BACKFEED
+000                LABEL TOP
+0000               LEFT POSITION
DISABLED            REPRINT MODE
013                 WEB SENSOR
096                 MEDIA SENSOR
000                 TAKE LABEL
062                 MARK SENSOR
004                 MARK MED SENSOR
020                 TRANS GAIN
004                 TRANS LED
032                 MARK GAIN
080                 MARK LED
DPCSWFXM            MODES ENABLED
........            MODES DISABLED
832 8/MM FULL      RESOLUTION
6.7                 LINK-OS VERSION
V93.21.17Z <-       FIRMWARE
1.3                 XML SCHEMA
7.0.1               HARDWARE ID
8176k............R: RAM
65536k...........E: ONBOARD FLASH
NONE                FORMAT CONVERT
FW VERSION          IDLE DISPLAY
04/17/24            RTC DATE
10:45               RTC TIME
DISABLED            ZBI
2.1                 ZBI VERSION
READY               ZBI STATUS
1,514 LABELS        NONRESET CNTR
1,514 LABELS        RESET CNTR1
1,514 LABELS        RESET CNTR2
13,946 IN           NONRESET CNTR
13,946 IN           RESET CNTR1
13,946 IN           RESET CNTR2
35,424 CM           NONRESET CNTR
35,424 CM           RESET CNTR1
35,424 CM           RESET CNTR2
002 WIRED,SERIAL    SLOT 1
0                   MASS STORAGE COUNT
0                   HID COUNT
OFF                 USB HOST LOCK OUT
